# getting empty response from aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Getting empty result for this query,record is there in the database.

```
db.portcall.find([
  {
    "$match": {
      "vesselCode": "Q3Y"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "arrivalVoyageCode": "128S"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "complianceReference.type": "Advance Manifest"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "complianceReference.loadPort": "EGPSDTM"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "estimatedArrivalDate": {
        "$lt": "2021-08-15T24:01:00Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "estimatedArrivalDate": {
        "$gt": "2021-08-15T22:01:00Z"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: For a very brief look, there are 2 strange places of your query in my eye: 1. you are using find instead of aggregate 2. the last 2 $match are matching based on strings of dates. Is the `estimatedArrivalDate` a string field or a date field?

Comment: You may also want to paste your sample data into [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) and share to anyone else here to have a look

Answer (score 1):

Check if each word is spelled correctly.

```
db.portcall.find({
  "vesselCode": "Q3Y",
  "arrivalVoyageCode": "128S",
  "complianceReference.type": "Advance Manifest",
  "complianceReference.loadPort": "EGPSDTM",
  "estimatedArrivalDate": {
    "$lt": "2021-08-15T24:01:00Z",
    "$gt": "2021-08-15T22:01:00Z"
  }
})
```